# Efficient Sequence conversion to String

Tags: performance, scala, out-of-memory

I have a string sequence `Seq[String]` which represents stdin input lines.

Those lines map to a model entity, but it is not guaranteed that 1 line = 1 entity instance.

Each entity is delimited with a special string that will not occur anywhere else in the input.

My solution was something like:

```
val entities = lines.mkString.split(myDelimiter).map(parseEntity)
```

`parseEntity` implementation is not relevant, it gets a String and maps to a case class which represents the model entity

The problem is with a given input, I get an OutOfMemoryException on the `lines.mkString`. Would a fold/foldLeft/foldRight be more efficient? Or do you have any better alternative?

Comment: Just a little point to consider. Even when you will find a workaround for exhausting memory during `mkString`, the same problem may reoccur for map(parseEntity), as probably collection of all created entities will need similar amount of memory as the raw string.

Comment: Can you change the way you read your input so you read each entity into a string instead of each line?  That would be the best way to improve this.

Comment: @puhlen no, i can't control the source...

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using akka streams and delimiter framing. See [this section](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#cookbook-parse-lines-scala) of the documentation for the basic approach.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Framing, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString

val example = (0 until 100).mkString("delimiter").grouped(8).toIndexedSeq
val framing = Framing.delimiter(ByteString("delimiter"), 1000)

implicit val system = ActorSystem()

implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

Source(example)
  .map(ByteString.apply)
  .via(framing)
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .runForeach(println)
```

The conversion to and from ByteString is a bit annoying, but Framing.delimiter is only defined for ByteString.

If you are fine with a more pure functional approach, [fs2](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) will also offer primitives to solve this problem.

Comment: could elaborate a bit more please? I'm not familiar with akka streams

Comment: thanks! although I would prefer not to add a new dependency just to this problem, I will have a look

Comment: fs2 doesn't have a built in way to split on an arbitrary delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me if you are reading from a stream (your mileage may vary). Slightly modified version of Scala `LineIterator`:

```
class EntityIterator(val iter: BufferedIterator[Char]) extends AbstractIterator[String] with Iterator[String] {
  private[this] val sb = new StringBuilder

  def getc() = iter.hasNext && {
    val ch = iter.next
    if (ch == '\n') false // Replace with your delimiter here
    else {
      sb append ch
      true
    }
  }

  def hasNext = iter.hasNext

  def next = {
    sb.clear
    while (getc()) { }
    sb.toString
  }
}

val entities =
  new EnityIterator(scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(...).iter.buffered)

entities.map(...)
```